# Graph: Why the fact that there are at most $5-|B|$ independent path is a contradiction?

Tags: graph-theory

I don't understand why the fact that there is at most $5-|B|$ independent path is a contradiction (see picture below).

[image]

Comment: What is $TK_7$?

Comment: A topological minor (or a subdivision) of $K_7$.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but I don't see how the statement is true. Let $G$ be $K_7$, $G_1$ be every vertex except one, and $G_2$ be the excluded vertex and one other. Then $G_1 \cup G_2 = G$, and $|G_1 \cap G_2| = 1$, but neither $G_1$ nor $G_2$ contains all the branch vertices.

Comment: @ZachGershkoff What edges are in your $G_1$ and $G_2$? The two graphs must contain all of the edges of $K_7$ also.

Answer (score 2):

Let $a_1 = |A_1|$, $a_2 = |A_2|$, and $b = |B|$. You have the following constraints:

- $a_1, a_2 \geq 1$, and $b \geq 0$ are integers
- $a_1 + a_2 + b = 7$
- $a_1 \cdot a_2 \leq 5 - b$

Suppose $a_1 = 1$, then $a_1 \cdot a_2 = a_2 = 7 - a_1 - b = 6 - b > 5 - b$, a contradiction to the third constraint. Arrive at a similar contradiction if $a_2 = 1$. So $a_1,a_2 \geq 2$, but then $a_1 \cdot a_2 \geq 2 \cdot \max(a_1,a_2) \geq a_1 + a_2 = 7 - b > 5 - b$, again a contradiction to the third constraint.

Answer (score 1):

The constraints in Perry Elliot-Iverson's answer are correct, but here's another way to see the contradiction. We have $|B| + |A_1| + |A_2| = 7$ and $|A_1| \cdot |A_2| \leq 5 - |B|$. If this system is solvable at all, it must be solvable when $(|A_1| \cdot |A_2|)$ is minimal, so without loss of generality we can take $|A_2| = 1$.

Then after some rearranging our system becomes $|A_1| + |B| = 6$ and $|A_1| + |B| \leq 5$, which clearly has no solution.